# Squares in $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $p\neq 2$, then I want to understand that every element in $\mathbb Z_p$ (p-adic integers) is a square.

For the prove one must see that $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_p$. But $2$ is the element $(...,2 \mod p^2,2\mod p)=(...,2,2,2)$

What is the inverse of this in $\mathbb Z_p$? We are talking about the inverse in terms of multiplication, right?

---

Edit: From the comments and the linked material it became clear that the question is about why the elements of the *multiplicative* group $1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$ are all squares. That group is isomorphic to the *additive* group  $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and this may have created some confusion. JL

Comment: what you have written in the first sentence is false.

Comment: I like the treatment of p-adic numbers in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, tables about your question approximately page 40-43. http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html

Comment: But then what is explained here? http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/MA598/Serre-Course%20in%20Arithmetic.pdf  --- p.18 first 5 lines.

Comment: Read the statement of Theorem 3 on the bottom of page 17. It very clearly states exactly which elements are squares. Those first five lines prove it (in particular proving that not all elements are squares).—Also, the invertibility of 2 in $\Bbb Z_p$, while true, is irrelevant to which elements are squares.

Comment: I dont understand the conclusion: "but $U_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$ and $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_p$; all the elements of $U_1$ are then squares, can you explain, please?

Comment: $2$ is the element $(\ldots,0,0,0,2)$. And $2^{-1}$ is the element $(\ldots,\frac12(p-1),\frac12(p-1),\frac12(p-1),\frac12(p+1))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ form a ring, which is both an additive group and a monoid under multiplication. When the textbook says "$U_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$", they mean the group $U_1$ under multiplication is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb Z_p$ **under addition**. So the analogue of a "square" in the relevant sense is an element of the form $y=x+x=2x$. This equation has the solution $x=2^{-1}y$, where yes, $2^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$.

In general, $2^{-1}$ is an element of the field $\mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers. If $p\neq2$ then $|2|_p=1$, so we also have $|2^{-1}|_p=1$ and $2^{-1}\in\mathbb Z_p$. So if $y\in\mathbb Z_p$, then $2^{-1}y\in\mathbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to use the isomorphism between $U_1$ and $\Bbb Z_p$ (when $p\ne2$) to show that every element of $U_1$ is a square. Two methods: (1) your element of $U_1$ has form $1+pz$ for some $z\in\Bbb Z_p$. Then the binomial expansion for $(1+pz)^{1/2}$ converges because the only denominators in the series are powers of $2$ (units in $\Bbb Z_p$) and the powers of $pz$ go to zero.

(2) the equation $X^2-(1+pz)$ looks like $(X-1)(X+1)$ modulo the maximal ideal, and by (the strong form of) Hensel’s Lemma, these two factors are relatively prime in $\Bbb F_p[X]$, so the factorization lifts from characteristic $p$ to characteristic zero.